# I can't find my module in Odoo8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

it must create my module on addons of odoo ? or in back of my project because when I add the project on add ons of odoo it be show on local module but when i remove from addons he doesn't 
I'm using odoo V8 with pycharm 2017
python 2.7 
NB:odoo is working fine on localhost

Answer (score 0):

might be you have two points

1) If you have added your module on different path from based addons then add that custom path on odoo config.

2) Restart odoo service. and Goto setting - > Activate Developer Mode -> Update App list -> then find your app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: are u talking about this 
script parameter : --config="/home/dhia/Desktop/configfile/file8.txt"

and file8 content this
[options]

addons_path =/home/dhia/Desktop/odooVersion8/odoo/addons,/home/dhia/PycharmProjects/untitled3
Xmlrpc_port=8070

Comment: addons_path=/home/system/workspace/odoo_v8/openerp/addons,/home/krishna/workspace/system/addons,/home/system/project/custom8

Comment: with this method module don't add on odoo localhost can i add on addons of odoo ?